# reporting services Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, iis-6, ssrs

I've got reporting services and sql server 2005 installed on a windows server 2003 enterprise sp2 server.  Reporting services was working just fine until yesterday it started saying "Error- Unable to connect to the remote server".  I'm really not sure where to start to look for fixing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manager went into Reporting Services and set everything to defaults (everything already set) and applied the settings, and it did something that fixed the issue.